# how to display the congratulation view in game using objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an App for preschool learning game for kids.So ,i have created ViewController for learning 1-10 numbers .This is my code:

```
 numbersStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png",@"10.png", nil];
    commonFunctionObject = [[SpeechCommonFunctions alloc]init];
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    counter = 0;
    isMicPresent = YES;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatActionFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)repeatActionFire
{
    if(counter >= numbersStoreArray.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_numbersShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];
    }
    else
    {
        [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:numbersStoreArray :counter :_numbersShowImageView :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [commonFunctionObject recordPlayAction];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    counter+=1;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}

- (IBAction)retryButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}
```

After the completion of game,it reaches to code repeatActionFire and it gives finished.Here i used congratzview to display the congratulation to success the game.
My question : i need to display the congralution view and in that two button .

buttons for:1.home
            2.retry

i need to do this how to do

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by displaying notice? If yes try this

**1. You Must Define a local notification**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self setupLocalNotifications];    
}

- (void)setupLocalNotifications {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    // current time plus 10 secs
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dateToFire = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];

    NSLog(@"now time: %@", now);
    NSLog(@"fire time: %@", dateToFire);

    localNotification.fireDate = dateToFire;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Time to get up!";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // increment

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

**2. Register the notification**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        [self showAlarm:notification.alertBody];
        NSLog(@"AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [self showAlarm:notification.alertBody];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate didReceiveLocalNotification %@", notification.userInfo);
}
```

**and 3. Display the notifications**

```
- (void)showAlarm:(NSString *)text {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm"
                                                        message:text delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

I use it to display messages from app, hope it can helps you

Comment: sorry ,i does't need to show the notification.I have edited my code please check